# HTML link with padding and CSS style active does not work

Tags: html, css, anchor, padding

HTML link with padding and CSS style active does not work in Google Chrome, Apple Safari, Opera, Mozilla Firefox. However, it works in Internet Explorer 8.

Here is an example code. Try to click on Stack - link does not work, click on Overflow - link works. By works I mean - navigate to StackOverflow site.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>css active padding href problem</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            a{
                display: inline-block;
                background:#CCC;
                border:1px solid #666;
                padding:0 35px 0 0;
            }
            a:active{
                padding:0 0 0 35px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>Click on <i>Stack</i> - href does not work.
               Click on <i>Overflow</i> - href works.
               All browsers are affected.
               Except IE.</p>
            <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why it does not work in most Browsers?

**Edit 2:** If you change :active to :hover, then everything works as expected in all Browsers - click happens and Browser navigates to stackoverflow.com

**Edit 3:** To prove that it is possible to click on padding area you can change style to:

```
<style type="text/css">
    a{
        padding:0 0 0 35px;
    }
</style>
```

If link "moves" as someone mentioned, then why it is possible to click on already "moved" link?

Comment: Updated code - added background and border to clarify that object does not move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With padding the text moves away from where you clicked. This is your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/ctrlfrk/3KsRx/

hold down the mouse button on 'Stack' and you will see that the text moves away from under the mouse.

What are you trying to achieve? This is working the way it should. If internet explorer follows the link then it is wrong.

[Edit]
Clarifying:

The real problem here is that a 'click' event only seems to fire if the mousedown event target matches the mouseup event target.
When you click on the text in your example, the mousedown target is a `text node` which is a child of the `anchor` tag. 
This `text node` then moves away, so that the mouseup event target is simply the `anchor` tag itself.

With :hover, the text node moves away before you click, so the mousedown event target is the `anchor` tag, and the mouseup event is also the `anchor` tag, so the link is followed.

[/Edit]

Comment: Text moves away, but background and border does not. Are you saying that Anchor can only be text, and not the padding area? Also, this does not explain :hover

Comment: Just tested, and removing text from anchor indeed fixes problem.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution!
http://jsfiddle.net/rydl/Yu6vp/3/

David is right, the problem is caused by the moving text-node. So the solution must prevent the text-node from being clicked at all. I used the anchor's :after-pseudo-element to cover the whole button, while being invisible:

```
a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: ' ';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Worked for me :)

Comment: I had a similar issue with pressing the mouse on a link but slightly moving the cursor. In this case sometimes browsers thought I want to drag and the click didn't trigger. Thanks for this!

Comment: best answer ever : I use an :active status having a slightly different layout (say 1px less for padding top for simulate 3D gap pressing), so there was 2 horizontal line areas of 1px, behind and below link label (but inside the link area) where click didn't work, tried to play with line-height instead, etc, same. But this clever one fixes the normal/active clicking area trouble definitively.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the padding with margin, As the padding is changed element position changes as well.

```
a {
    margin:0 0 0 35px;
}
```

To browsers(firefox,chrome etc) A valid mouse click is one which is **pressed and released on same element**.

EDIT: I cant change the behavior of browser (*no solution in pure css*), but you can use javascript to get this done

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" onmousedown="window.location=this;">StackOverflow</a>
```

EDIT: *:hover* works instead *:active* because of the reason **as element does not change position between time pressed and time released**

Comment: you should use margin instead of padding (changing element position is the issue)

Comment: See updated code. With padding object does not move. When using margin - object moves. I need padding.

Comment: onmousedown works, but it is not user friendly. onmouseup also works, and it has side-effect, that you can click anywhere and release on anchor. onclick is most desirable - but it does not work. Still waiting for better solution. Currently onmouseup seems the best workaround. Thank you.