# Where should I report a bug - Firefox or Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, anchor, padding, w3c

Internet Explorer behaves differently from Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari. See my question: 
[HTML link with padding and CSS style active does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280522/html-link-with-padding-and-css-style-active-does-not-work)

Is this undefined behavior? Or I need to report a bug. If later, then which of browsers are doing right?

Here is a test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>css active padding href problem</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            a{
                background:#CCC;
                border:1px solid #666;
                padding:0 35px 0 0;
            }
            a:active{
                padding:0 0 0 35px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>Click on <i>Stack</i> - href does not work.
               Click on <i>Overflow</i> - href works.
               All browsers are affected.
               Except IE.</p>
            <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think IE is doing wrong. a:active is working when the mousebutton is down, but the href doesn't go off before the mousebutton is up again.

Pseudo-code:

```
onmousedown(e) {
  setCssAsActive();
}
onmouseup(e) {
  activateHref();
}
```

If the mouse goes up outside of the element, nothing happends. Try to click on a link, then drag your mouse away from the link and then release the button. Nothing should happend.

That is what happening in your code. When you are clicking at the Stack-text, the link moves away fron your pointer, and when you release the button, the link is no longer under the pointer. It moves back at the release-time, but then it is too late.

Therefore, I think IE is doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I think is in the IE box model, as stated here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug

As the link say IE includes the padding in the box, which is why the link works on IE but not any other browser, this is proven by changing the padding to margin in the example above, or here http://jsfiddle.net/S5dGw/

Although most(including myself) would say this is an IE bug, some would say the this is a W3C issue with specs. http://www.crossbrowser.net/82/internet-explorer-box-model-is-not-a-bug/ *scoff*.

Not to worry when CSS3 is fully supported (it the distant future :) ), it will have the `box-sizing` attribute, that will fix this problem, see below:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing